# Empty flat error output file

Tags: ssis

I am working with a workflow that should kick out an input row to the error stream.  I have a DataFlow task which has within it a File Source node (let's call it AAA_Source) and a Flat File Destination (let's call it AAA_ErrorDest) on the error output from AAA_Source.

What I am seeing is that the AAA_ErrorDest file is created but always has zero bytes in it.  I also see that it's last-modified date is changed during an import operation but still the file size does not change.

I have pursued a file permissions approach but all parties have write access to the file.  It does not matter whether I run it from within BIDS or run DTEXEC from the command line.  (Using SQL Server 2012, by the way.)

I noticed that the error output was three columns:  the input file line, an error code, and an error column ordinal.   I also noticed that the Connection Manager for the error output file had all three columns mapped but the text column had a length of 50 (too short).   However, when I changed that length to 300 (not too short), it had no effect--still nothing got written to the error file (but its last-modified timestamp was changed).

So, how do I determine why there is no text going to my error file?

Comment: Is error data being generated? The file will always be created regardless of whether rows flow to it but if your source doesn't have errors, one would expect that file to remain empty

Comment: I have N rows that come in and N-200 rows that come out to the table.   The dropped rows should show up in the error output but nothing shows up there. (BTW, N is about 3.1 million)

Comment: Before someone asks, I should note that the Error action for each column in the input source is "Redirect row" and the "Truncation" action for each column in the input source is set to "Fail component".
As I understand it, this implies that any problems with any column should redirect the row to the error output.